# Material Preview suddenly all black

Tags: materials, color

I'm in Blender 2.82.7

I have a project on which I have worked for several days. I have been modeling a lot these last 2 days, and didn't give much attention on material preview.
When I came back to preview, I noticed that everything was black, but it was not before :
[image]

Compared to a new project :

[image]

It seems that the environment itself is all black. I have tried to change the surface type, its color, Sky Texture, but it always remains black.

Maybe I have stroke a wrong shortcut keyboard during 2 days of modeling that has deactivated "something", but I'm short of ideas!

If anyone could help, I would appreciate ! :-)

Thanks

Comment: While in material preview mode, click the arrow next to the preview buttons, and in the menu that appears, make sure "strength" and "world opacity" have some value (defaults are 1 and 0.5, respectively) and that neither "scene world" or "scene lights" are checked.

Comment: update to version 2.83

Comment: Well, I don't have an "answer", but it solved itself. I switched to eevee then back to cycles, from Render to Render Preview, and it came back.
Seems more like a bug (software, or hardware) than a subtlety I couldn't catch, but not sure.